# Delphi 2006: I'm trying to call a function of a class, but I'm not familiar with the VAR type parameter

Tags: delphi, pointers, parameters, casting, procedure

Here is the function I'm trying to call:

function TPipeClient.Write(var Buffer; Count: Integer): Boolean;

I have another class that is a queue of tMessages to write:

```
tMessage = class
  public
    function getData(): PByte; virtual; abstract;
    function getLen(): integer; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

So when I try to call: TPipeClient.Write like this:

```
FClient.Write(queue[pos].getData(), queue[pos].getLen());
```

(Fclient is a tClientPipe, queue is array of tMessage)

I get an error saying no matching overlaoded version that matches, so I do a:

```
FClient.Write(@(queue[pos].getData()), queue[pos].getLen());
```

And I get another compile error: Variable required.

Any ideas on how I can cast this so it will pass and get sent out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an [untyped `var` parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Untyped_Parameters) which is covered in some detail by the documentation. In short you need to pass a variable.

In your case you'll need to define one:

```
var
  P: PByte;
```

And you can then call your function like this:

```
P := queue[pos].getData();
FClient.Write(P^, queue[pos].getLen());
```

Comment: That did it!  I knew it was something simple.  I'm trying to rush some stuff out and got stuck on that.  Oh and thanks for catching the @ vs % mistake I was about to make. :)